# Url route with datetime for web api in asp.net webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

[using WEB Api 1.0]
Need to configured the action with the following GET url

> api/v1/Customer/{Id}/Instances/find?start_date={startDate}&end_date={endDate}

Where id,startDate and endDate 3 parameters are mandatory

The webapiconfig is as below for the method

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "CustomerInstances",
                    routeTemplate: "api/v1/Customer/{id}/Instances/find",
                    defaults: new { controller = "api", action = "CustomerInstances" });
```

The ApiController action is as below

```
[HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Customer> CustomerInstances(int id,DateTime startDate,DateTime endDate)
        {
return customer;
}
```

Please help me i am stuck as i get the error
Issue 1:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'startDate' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method
>   'CustomeInstances(Int32, System.DateTime,System.DateTime)' in
>   'apiController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a
>   nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

Issue 2
I even tried to make Datetime as nullable i.e Datetime? startDate=null  but i get startDate as null all the time the values are not getting bind not sure why.

This seems to be weird 
Thanks in advance

Comment: My bad seems i have added code to not to accept values from querystring config.Services.Replace(typeof(ValueProviderFactory), new RouteDataValueProviderFactory())   this is causing the issue. Need to remove it  thanks solved the issue

Comment: please consider re-posting this comment as an Answer, then mark it as correct.